# Block new event from being attached to an element

Tags: javascript

I am binding event to an element.

How to prevent new JavaScript event to be bound to it?

I want to prevent unknown scripts to play with my elements.

Comment: This is a comment because I'm not sure I'm correct but can't you just use `myElement.onclick = (function(){ /* your code here */ });` to override previous attached event listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot block an unknown script from attaching an event listener to your object.  The browser does not offer that feature.  The browser does block scripts that are running from other domains (other windows, tab, or frames) from messing with your DOM, but if a script is in the same domain or even in the same page, it is free to do whatever it wants to the DOM in that page.

If you have problems with unknown scripts doing bad things, then you're probably better off backing way, way up and describing what you're really trying to protect against because trying to block an event listener is like trying to keep someone out of one drawer when they're already roaming free through your house.  You probably need to secure things at a much higher level.

---

If you want to get into the realm of "hacking" to try to block specific types of code, there are some options.  These aren't foolproof if the 3rd party code wants to get around them.  In other words, these would be more useful if you can see what the 3rd party code does and it won't adapt itself to try to get around you:

Firstly, you can replace `elem.addEventListener()` after you've installed your event handler which will prevent other code from using `elem.addEventListener()` on that object again.

```
var item = document.getElementById("test");
item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    log("original event handler");
});

// install "do nothing" override method
item.oldAddEventListener = item.addEventListener;
item.addEventListener = function() {};

// this one will do nothing because addEventListener has been replaced
item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    log("2nd event handler");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/C5rzN/

This isn't foolproof as there are other ways to still install an event handler calling the method directly from the prototype or using the `onclick` property.

Comment: thanks for confirming this. I saw event.stopImmediatePropagation() from jQuery that keeps the rest of handlers to be executed. If I attach my handler to an element before the unknown script does, and call stopImmediatePropagation, it should prevents unwanted events to be trigger, isn't?

Comment: @arsenik - I think that `stopImmediatePropagation()` only prevents other jQuery event handlers from executing (event handlers added with jQuery), not event handlers installed with plain JS.  What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to prevent a third party script (adware) user installed from manipulating some elements of my page. I do not want to completely disabled this third party script, but only to prevent it from interacting (be over, change aspect, ...) of some elements.

Comment: @arsenik - you'd get much better feedback if you were a lot more specific about exactly what the adware is doing because there is no generic answer here, you can only try to defeat exactly what the adware is doing.  I did add one specific idea to my answer.

Comment: thanks, your example makes sense and gives me ideas on own to prevent this. adware code is well uglyfied, and I can just guess what it is using to attach event. I will give this a shot and let you know.

Comment: I figured out this adware is adding an attribute to img tag element it targets. Once the attribute is on the element, a mouse over on it will show an ad. Do you know if I can prevent this attribute to be set in the first place? @jfriend00

Comment: @arsenik - There is no way to prevent an attribute being set on your object.  If it's truly an attribute (and not a property), then in the latest browsers, it's possible to use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to be notified when attributes are added or modified, or continuing in the "hack" department, you can could use fire a `setInterval()` for a couple seconds after the page loads to find any of these attributes and remove them.

Comment: attribute removal makes no difference, mousemove event is already bound. Actually I did el.addEventListener = function(){}; but it did not prevent the event to be attached later on. Is it possible to detach an event? @jfriend00

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51948/discussion-between-arsenik-and-jfriend00)

Comment: @arsenik - it's not very productive here for me to just guess possible solutions without seeing the actual code you're trying to block so I can figure out which of hundreds of strategies might work there.